# Why is accessing these particular videos with ffmpeg far slower than usual?

Tags: linux, video, ffmpeg, video-processing

If I run `ffmpeg -ss $TIME -i $URL -frames:v 1 -filter:v $FILTER file.jpg -v trace` to get a screenshot of a video from a remote website, it normally runs quite quickly. But videos from a different website are taking much longer to run.

All videos from one particular website are very slow. I've compared two videos that are 3-4MB, one from a website where ffmpeg works almost instantly (0.5 seconds) and another from a website where it works terribly slowly (15 seconds).

Here's the trace output for the slow video http://pastebin.pl/view/raw/4df9fb06. And here's trace output for the fast video http://pastebin.pl/view/raw/4b590932.

Can you identify any reason why one video is so much slower compared to all the other videos? The ffmpeg command I ran is the one from above and the same for both videos. How can I speed this up?

The slow video downloads a few seconds slower than the fast video, but I don't think the ffmpeg command should be showing such a major difference between the two files.

Comment: Perhaps they don't support http range requests so it has to download full videos?

Answer (score 2):

The "fast video" is a regular MP4 with its index upfront. The "slow video" is a fragmented MP4, formatted for [DASH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Adaptive_Streaming_over_HTTP), with the samples indices, distributed across the file. To locate the samples that you are seeking to, ffmpeg has to parse the indices, so it has to download a lot more, if not the entire file.

Comment: If I access the "slow video" mp4 file URL in the browser, it takes a long time before it starts playing. If I do it with the "fast video" URL it starts streaming almost immediately. In the Chrome browser Network tab the fast video shows a 206 HTTP request which starts streaming, so the response gets larger and larger and the video starts playing. But for the slow video it does hundreds of small 206 HTTP requests (e.g. `Range:bytes=57540608-62610843` followed by `Range:bytes=57769984-62610843`) before anything starts playing. Is this just how DASH works or can anything be sped up?

Comment: I expect that's how fragmented files work, although I don't know the details of how browsers handle DASH.